# useEffect infinitely loops when I include a dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom useFetch hook and it works in every component except one. In this one component it infinitely loops (but not so much that React stops it). This is the hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, SetStateAction, Dispatch } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const useFetch = (
  method: 'POST' | 'GET',
  url: string,
  object?: any
): [
  AxiosResponse,
  'Loading' | 'Rendered' | 'Error',
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<'Loading' | 'Rendered' | 'Error'>>
] => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AxiosResponse | null | void>(null);
  const [compState, setCompState] = useState<'Loading' | 'Rendered' | 'Error'>('Loading');

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    setCompState('Loading');
    if (method === 'GET') {
      // ...
    } else if (
      method === 'POST' &&
      object !== null &&
      !Object.values(object).includes(null)
    ) {
      axios
        .post(url, object)
        .then(res => {
          if (isMounted) {
            console.log(res.data);
            setCompState('Rendered');
            setData(res);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (isMounted) {
            console.log(err);
            setCompState('Error');
            setData(err);
          }
        });
    } else return;

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [url, object]); 

  return [data as AxiosResponse, compState];
};

export default useFetch;
```

This is how I'm using it in the component:

```js
  const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
  const [orders, compState] = useFetch('POST', '/orders', { userId });
```

I know part of what is causing the loop; it's because I have the `object` in the dependency array, and that if I remove it from the array, it stops looping. The problem is that I need the `object` in the array because, in this case, the object is just the userId, and I want the component to rerender when the user signs in on this page. I assume that something about the userId constant is the cause of this problem.

Before I extracted the custom hook, the constant was in the useEffect and this wasn't a problem, but I'm wondering if theirs a way to fix this that doesn't affect the reusability of the hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try as below because **useEffect** uses **shallow comparison**, so 2 objects {} and {} are not the same, then it can lead to infinite render.

```js
JSON.stringify(object)
```

Comment: thank you, adding this to the dependency array fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass `objects` as an array item of second `useEffect` parameter if you wanting deep property comparison on that object so the best way of doing that if you need a deep comparison on `object`s properties would be using `use-deep-compare-effect` as bellow:

```
import useDeepCompareEffect from 'use-deep-compare-effect';

// Later in our components
useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    setCompState('Loading');
    if (method === 'GET') {
      // ...
    } else if (
      method === 'POST' &&
      object !== null &&
      !Object.values(object).includes(null)
    ) {
      axios
        .post(url, object)
        .then(res => {
          if (isMounted) {
            console.log(res.data);
            setCompState('Rendered');
            setData(res);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (isMounted) {
            console.log(err);
            setCompState('Error');
            setData(err);
          }
        });
    } else return;

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [url, object]);
```